# Split View Controller and UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, uisplitviewcontroller

I am attempting to use a split view controller with a Detail View Controller that shows a web site. The code of the Detail View Controller is as follows:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    var detailItem: Article? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view.
            self.configureView()
        }
    }

    func configureView() {
        // Update the user interface for the detail item.
        if let detail = self.detailItem?.html {
            let url = NSURL(string: "http://myWebsite.com" + detail)
            println(url)
            let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
            println(requestObj)
            webView.loadRequest(requestObj)
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run the program, both `println()` show results. But the program throws an exception:

> Optional(http://myWebsite.com/foo)
>
> { URL: http://myWebsite.com/foo } fatal
>   error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Why did it find nil? The optional value has a value?

Comment: Why are you defining url as a constant but then unwrapping it?

Comment: I don't understand? It shouldn't make a difference if I use let or var. I assume that loadrequest( ) unwraps requestObj? I thought the code would be "cleaner" like this.

Comment: what line is it saying it found the nil? `webView.loadRequest(requestObj)`?

Comment: Yes exactly. webView.loadRequest(requestObj)

Comment: Your `webView` is nil

Comment: Do I need to initialize it somehow? I thought it was good enough to use .loadRequest.

Comment: That would probably be a good idea if you want your code to run :)

Comment: Does not work. If I set up the first page it works:

Comment: What do you mean if you set up the first page?

Comment: I set up mywebsite.com in viewDidLoad( ) with the same code (but without the self.detailitem?.html and it shows perfectly. It only throws an exception when I call configureView( ).

Comment: Can you do a `println(webView)` in your `configureView()`?

Comment: Part of the issue might be the timing of the call. You are placing a listener and calling on the didSet. Its entirely possible webView doesn't exist at that point.

Comment: Got it, thanks for your help! I need to make @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView? instead of UIWebView! Your input with the println( ) got me to the answer.

Comment: Yes you are right. Placing a listener without webView existing yet.

Comment: Be sure to mark question complete with an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webView is nil

Your didSet listener is calling your code before you webView object exists. You need to ensure you webView exists by the time you call it.